# Django: Is it possible to filter on QueryDict?

Tags: django

Within my `form.data` I have a QueryDict.

```
    QueryDict: <QueryDict: {u'deal_status_2': [u'1'], 
                     u'deal_status_1': [u'2'], u'subject': [u'wdes']}>
```

`deal_status_1` and `deal_status_2` are both dynamically generated as part of the form through jquery.

Nowhere else on the POST form could I find them but in form.data.

Which is fine, now I need the values.

So I thought it would be great if I could filter on QueryDict like this

```
var array = form.data.filter(???__istartswith('deal_status_')
```

and get an array of all the dynamically generated fields I need to iterate through and grab the value from.

Is this possible?  what do I put for `???` in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not possible.

Try this:

```
my_data = []
for q, v in form.data.items():
    if q.startswith('deal_status_'):
        my_data += v
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes use:

```
query = querydict

ModelObject.filter(**query.dict())
```

https://coderwall.com/p/gtwm1q/pass-a-querydict-to-a-django-queryset